# How to get a list of followed people, followed topics and followers using Yammer API

Tags: yammer

For a given user (or current user) is it possible to get the people they are following, the topics they are following and the people that are following them?

Answer (score 3):

you can write REST API and using that you can get

For Followers 
https://api.yammer.com/api/v1/users/following/*userid.json

For Following 
https://api.yammer.com/api/v1/users/followed_by/*userid.json

*userid = id of yammer user

Please refer https://developer.yammer.com/restapi/

Answer (score 0):

Small correction in the url

For Followers: https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/users/following/.json
For Following: https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/users/followed_by/.json

Replace  with Yammer user id.

Correction is in the domain name: Instead of 'api.yammer.com' its 'www.yammer.com'